# How to change the Font of Outlooks folder list?

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2003

Some Colleagues asked me how to change the font or font size of the Folders inside Outlook 2003 (Inbox, Sent Items and so on)

I searched all the View-Options inside Outlook and changed "every" other appearance for the Email-Lists but I cant find any option for the List of folders.

I tried to change the general appearance of Windows XP, but did not find any option for this issue - I just changed the appearance of Menus, Windowtitles, ...

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to only change the folder list font in Outlook 2003 with Windows XP...

Comment: seems to be the correct Answer - i tried several other options (and also the other answer below) and nothing seemed to change it.

"it's not a bug, it's a feature!"

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer to this at http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread251136.html.  view -> arrange by -> current view -> customize current view -> other settings.  You can select the font sizes for everything.  You have to do it for each folder, though.  But, it works!

Comment: that is not what I want. I want to change the font of the Mail-FOLDERS not the Font of the Mails.
the referred website asks for the Formatting of the Mails.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution I found that works !

http://blogmines.com/blog/2011/11/15/how-to-change-font-size-of-folders-in-outlook-2010/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. As you might have seen this Question related to Windows XP and Outlook 2003, where your Answer is given for Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook, and many Windows programs, use the default font for icons. In XP it's Tahoma, in Vista and Windows 7 it's Segoe UI.

There's no built-in solution in Outlook or Windows to change fonts individually for every program. Your best bet is to change to font for *all* icons, but then again, that will effect **all** programs.

[image]

Comment: I just tried this on my Outlook 2003 / Windows XP config and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works in Outlook 2003, but it works in **Outlook 2010** (probably there are some people that found this question looking for another Outlook version - I am one of them).

- From the bottom left corner, **right click on Mail** > **Navigation Pane Options...**:

  [image]
- Click on **Font**:

  [image]
- Choose a font size and click on **OK**:

  [image]
- Click **OK** to confirm:

  [image]

The font size for the left pane was changed immediately, so you don't need to restart Outlook to see that change.